# Create a 3rd dataframe that counts common values with first two

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm struggling to think of where to start so apologies for not having any code to reference.

I have two dataframes. Let's call it

df1 = chefs

[image]

df2 = Recipes

[image]

Each chef can only make recipes that are equal or less hard than their skill level. So chef A can only make Easy and Medium recipes while Chef E can make all recipes.

My goal is to create something like below that adds up the number of ingredients the chef has for each recipe he or she can make to give output kinda like below. For scale/efficiency reference there are about 100ish chefs and about 2000 recipes in my real dataset (which surprise isn't chefs and recipes but play along for now...). The below was made to reflect all the recipes each chef could make skill-wise. Ideally I wouldn't show recipes that have 0 matches in ingredients.
[image]

Thank you for any help! I have no clue where to start with merge() or isin(). I'm pretty new to Python but I can definitely read and understand code so don't feel the need to hold my hand through your code too much!!

Answer (score 2):

This seems relatively inefficient by looping through chefs and recipes to get the intersection of the chefs ingredients with the (filtered skill-level appropriate) recipe ingredients, but it works.

```
# create ordinal mapping for ease of comparison
ordinals = {'Easy': 0,
            'Medium': 1,
            'Hard': 2}

chefs['Ordinal_Difficulty'] = chefs['Difficulty'].map(ordinals)
recipes['Ordinal_Difficulty'] = recipes['Difficulty'].map(ordinals)

# create dictionary of chefs with their ingredients
chef_ingredients = {values[0]: list(values[2:-1]) for values in chefs.values}

# create dictionary of chefs with their skill levels
chef_skill = pd.Series(chefs['Ordinal_Difficulty'].values,index=chefs['Chef_ID']).to_dict()

# to be list of lists of chef_ID, recipe_ID, and common ingredient count
final_list = []

# loop through each chef (relatively inefficient)
for chef, ingredients in chef_ingredients.items():
    skill_level = chef_skill[chef] # grab their skill level to filter by
    # create dictionary of skill-appropriate recipes with their ingredients
    cookable_recipes = {values[0]: list(values[2:-1]) for values in recipes.values if values[-1] <= skill_level}
    # list comprehension containing chef ID, recipe ID, and number of common ingredients in each cookable recipe
    chefs_ingredients_per_cookable_recipe = [(chef, key, len(set(ingredients) & set(value))) for key, value in cookable_recipes.items()]
    # add to 'final_list' -- extending to flatten out lists
    final_list.extend(chefs_ingredients_per_cookable_recipe)

# convert final_list to DataFrame
match = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Chef_ID', 'Recipe', 'Count'])
```